# Is it idiomatic to say "Son, tuck your top under your chin while peeing"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

When our children learn to pee themselves, we need to tell them to hold the edge of their tops up high to their chins so that they don't pee on their tops.

These are the list of says that I think of:

- Hold **the edge of your top up** high **to** your chin while peeing.
- Hold **your top up** high **to** your chin while peeing.
- Hold **the edge of your top up** high **with** your chin while peeing.
- Tuck **your top under your chin** while peeing.

Which of the above sayings are idiomatic?

Answer (score 3):

Hold your **shirt** up, and tuck it under your chin.

When someone **pees themselves** it means they've had an accident and peed in their clothes, diaper, etc. When they learn to pee **by** themselves, they learn to do it without help. This is one aspect of **potty training** or **toilet training**.

If you deliberately said "top" to refer to something other than a shirt, it would be more idiomatic to say whatever it is (jumper, dress, blouse, etc.). Otherwise just say "shirt."

Comment: When my boy (who is now over 40) was at this stage, I just used to say "don't pee on your vest/shirt" and leave it up to his ingenuity to work out a method of achieving that goal.

Answer (score 1):

1. Hold your top up by/to your chin while peeing.
2. Tuck your top under your chin while peeing.

Both of the above are idiomatic but they have different meanings.

1 means hold your top with your hand(s).

2 means hold your top with your chin (after moving it there with your hand(s)).

Comment: "Catch your shirt under your chin" is what my mother would have said.